# Datetime format pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime-format

I am trying to read a csv and to convert the datetime column into a datetime index, but I am struggling with the format. How do you specify the +2 in the format parameter of `pd.to_datetime`?

Many thanks,

```
date  = ['2015-02-03 21:00:00+02:00','2015-02-03 22:30:00+02:00','2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00','2016-02-03   22:00:00+02:00']
value_column = [33.24  , 500  , 34.39  , 34.49 ]
        
df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':value_column}, index=pd.to_datetime(date,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
print(df.head())
    
                                 V1 
     index                                     
     2015-02-03 21:00:00+02:00  33.24   
     2015-02-03 22:30:00+02:00  500   
     2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00  34.39   
     2016-02-03 22:00:00+02:00  34.49
```

Comment: simplier is use `df = pd.DataFrame({'V1':value_column}, index=pd.to_datetime(date))`

Comment: Note that `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` does not agree with e.g. `'2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00'`, that would be `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z'`. Date/time string parsers don't do magic; please have a look at [strftime/strptime directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Also note that [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) allows to parse specific columns to datetime (`parse_dates=`) and set one as index (`index_col=`).

Answer (score 0):

Use `parse_dates=['date']` as parameter of `pd.read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                               V1
date                             
2015-02-03 21:00:00+02:00   33.24
2015-02-03 22:30:00+02:00  500.00
2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00   34.39
2016-02-03 22:00:00+02:00   34.49

>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2015-02-03 21:00:00+02:00', '2015-02-03 22:30:00+02:00',
               '2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00', '2016-02-03 22:00:00+02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]', name='date', freq=None)
```

Content of csv file:

```
date,V1
2015-02-03 21:00:00+02:00,33.24
2015-02-03 22:30:00+02:00,500
2016-02-03 21:00:00+02:00,34.39
2016-02-03 22:00:00+02:00,34.49
```